# An argument for 'payload' was not provided. error in component from service

Tags: angular

I have a form which has data posted to a web api. There is a service written for this and this is injected into the form component within the onSubmit function. I am getting an error of `An argument for 'payload' was not provided`. I don't see where the problem could be? My code so far is:

**service.ts**

```js
  postFormData(payload) {
    this.http.post(this.serviceApiUrl, payload, { headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json")});
 }
```

**component.ts**

```js
 constructor(private service: nowService,
    private appComponent: AppComponent,
    private router: Router,
    private http: HttpClient,
  ) {
  }

onSubmit() {
    if(this.serviceForm.invalid) {
       this.serviceForm.setErrors({ ...this.serviceForm.errors, 'required': true });
       return;
    }
    this.service.postFormData().subscribe((response: any) => {
      console.log(response);//On success response
      this.router.navigate(['confirmation']);
    }, (errorResponse: any) => {
      console.log(errorResponse); //On unsuccessful response
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: this.service.postFormData() is called with no argument?

Comment: postFormData should return an observable

Comment: right, should be: ´return this.http.post...´

Comment: Do you have a code example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you are calling the service, you need to pass the parameter payload from your component which is missing . Pass the parameter from component.ts

`this.service.postFormData(payload).subscribe((response: any)`

**EDIT**

Your parameters should be as,

```
this.service.postFormData(this.serviceForm.value).subscribe((response: any)
```

and before subscribing you should return the Observable from your service as

```
postFormData(payload) {
  //add return//
  return this.http.post(this.serviceApiUrl, payload, { headers: new HttpHeaders().set("Content-Type", "application/json")});
}
```

Comment: I get the following if i replace that line: (1)Cannot find name 'payload'. (2) Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: @Sole now should make sense

Answer (score 0):

Use form.value as shown below,

this.service.postFormData(***serviceForm.value***).subscribe(....);

Answer (score 0):

```js
generateProductImages(campaignId, prod_id) {
    return this.http.patch(CAMPAIGNS_URL.GENERATE_PRODUCT_IMAGES(campaignId, prod_id), {})
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Angular12. In your *postFormData* function there is one argument as "payload". When you call *postFormData* function inside a component you have pass a value to the argument. Otherwise you will get an error message in your service.